# Dispalying more than one message box one after other

Tags: extjs

I have requirement to show multiple info/alert messages one after other.

Here is my sample code

```
var messageQueueStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['type','Title','text','buttonConfig','callback'],
storeId: 'messageQueueStore'
});


function displayMessage(type, Title, Text, buttonConfig, callback){
messageQueueStore.loadData([{type: type, Title : Title, Text: Text, buttonConfig:buttonConfig, callback:callback}], true);
if(!Ext.MessageBox.isVisible()){
    displayEachMessage();
}
}

function displayEachMessage(){
var firstRecord = messageQueueStore.getAt(0);
//We are currently handling only alert messages. If needed this method can be extended to hande other type of messages
if(firstRecord.get('type') == 'alert'){
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title : firstRecord.get('Title'),
        msg : firstRecord.get('Text'),
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        listeners: {
                beforeclose : function(){console.log("Before close");},
                close : function(){console.log("close");},
                hide : function(){console.log("hide");},
                beforehide : function(){console.log("beforehide");},

            },
        fn : messageClosed
    })
    }
}

function messageClosed(){
    // before close event needs to be handled as well
    messageQueueStore.removeAt(0);
    if(messageQueueStore.count() != 0){
        displayEachMessage();
    }
}


// And this is how i use this functionality
displayMessage('alert','first',"You are now seeing the first message");
displayMessage('alert','second',"This is the second message");
displayMessage('alert','third',"Here comes the third");
displayMessage('alert','fourth',"And this is the last");
```

This works perfectly fine when user clicks on the OK button. However when user clicks on the (x) button on the message box top right corner none of the events i am trying to listen are triggered. 
And hence the subsequent messages are not displayed.

Any pointers on how to handle the close event on message box will be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/kTpct/2/

```
function myAlert(title, message){
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        width: 300,
        height: 120,
        autoDestroy: true,
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        bodyStyle: 'border:none; background-color: transparent;',
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: message
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Ok',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    fn: function (item, e) {
                        this.up('window').close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }).show();
}

for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) myAlert('message ' + i, 'content of message ' + i);
```

Comment: The above example works perfectly fine the way my expectation is. However my problem is this window visualization doesn't match with the Ext.messagebox UI. We have a lot of alert messages displayed across our application and all of them we cant replace at this point. Hence the new alert messages we are adding should also look similar to that of the existing once we have. Is there no way to get this done using ext.messagebox?

Comment: I think that this can not be m. Look: 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?39903-Multiple-Ext.Msg.alert-at-a-time but You can customize window like messagebox. and parent of Ext.window.MessageBox class is Ext.window.Window

Comment: I had added bodyStyle: 'border:none; background-color: transparent;', buttonAlign: 'center', for window customization and answer/sample was updated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with the Ext.MessageBox because it is a singleton and there is no way to guarantee that the previous alert was reset before you are updating the properties for the next alert. Only one can be visible at a time and back to back alerts with no blocking will cause you timing issues.

"Busy-Blocking" is also bad anyway because there is no "Await-Callback" in javascript.